# No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so',

Tags: ros2, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rolling CI for [RQt Image Overlay is failing](https://build.ros2.org/job/Rdev__rqt_image_overlay__ubuntu_jammy_amd64/10/console) on ROS Buildfarm with error message:

```
23:10:11 --- stderr: rqt_image_overlay
23:10:11 gmake[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so', needed by 'librqt_image_overlay.so'.  Stop.
23:10:11 gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/rqt_image_overlay.dir/all] Error 2
23:10:11 gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
23:10:11 ---
```

Ealier in the output of CMake, Python3.10 is found:

```
23:10:11 -- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.2") found components: Interpreter
```

[Ubuntu Jammy is transitioning to Python3.10](https://discourse.ros.org/t/preparing-for-rolling-sync-delayed-by-python-3-10-transition/24521/2?u=kenji_brameld), so I don't quite know which package is forcing `libpython3.9.so` to be looked for.

EDIT:
It seems that many other packages are also failing the same error, many from ros2 core libraries too:

- [Rdev__rclc__ubuntu_jammy_amd64](https://build.ros2.org/view/Rdev/job/Rdev__rclc__ubuntu_jammy_amd64/4/console)
- [Rdev__geometry2__ubuntu_jammy_amd64](https://build.ros2.org/view/Rdev/job/Rdev__geometry2__ubuntu_jammy_amd64/4/console)
- [Rdev__libstatistics_collector__ubuntu_jammy_amd64](https://build.ros2.org/view/Rdev/job/Rdev__libstatistics_collector__ubuntu_jammy_amd64/5/console)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397168/no-rule-to-make-target-%27/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so%27,/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2022-03-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2022-03-08**:
Related: https://answers.ros.org/question/397215/no-rule-to-make-libpython-when-using-rosidl_generate_interfaces-dependencies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has been resolved after ROS2 Rolling properly transitioned to Ubuntu Jammy .

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1